# Search in text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi A text file which has following entries

```
CHECK>ABC
   Battery:   OK
   RSA:       OK
 Health Check
CHECK>ABC Verbose
   Battery:   OK
     Battery:    voltage 1 2.3v
     Battery:    voltage 2 2.3v
   RSA:       OK
```

Health Check

I would like to get only following from the file

```
   Battery:   OK
   RSA:       OK
```

I have following code

```
start=r'^CHECK>ABC$'
end=r'^Health Check'
pattern = r'{p0}(?!.*{p0})(?:.*?{p1}|.*)'.format(p0=start, p1=end)
matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if matches:
    last_match = matches[-1]
    data.append(last_match.split('\n'))
    if not re.search(end, last_match, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
        print("error_no_end")
else:
    print("error_no_match")
```

it gives following information in data

```
CHECK>ABC Verbose
   Battery:   OK
     Battery:    voltage 1 2.3v
     Battery:    voltage 2 2.3v
   RSA:       OK       
Health Check
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are interested in Battery status and RSA status only, if yes, then these lines of code shall help you.

```
data = []
battery_status = re.search(r"\b(Battery)\s*:\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b", text)
data.append(battery_status.group(1) + ": " + battery_status.group(2))
rsa_status = re.search(r"\b(RSA)\s*:\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b", text)
data.append(rsa_status.group(1) + ": " + rsa_status.group(2))

data = "\n".join(data)
print(data)
```